# Set a different Page footer for each Page in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have tested the sample code in the corresponding [MSDN article](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Excel-2010-Work-with-c85cd29e):

```
Sub WorkWithPages() 
    ' Fill random data: 
    Range("A1", "R100").Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(1, 100)" 

    Dim pgs As Pages 
    Set pgs = PageSetup.Pages 

    PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True 

    ' Look in the Immediate window for this output: 
    Debug.Print "The current sheet can be printed on " & _ 
     pgs.Count & " page(s)." 

    Dim pg As Page 
    Set pg = pgs(1) 
    pg.CenterHeader.Text = "This is the first page's header" 

    Set pg = pgs(2) 
    pg.CenterFooter.Text = "This is the second page's footer" 

    Set pg = pgs(pgs.Count) 
    pg.CenterFooter.Text = "This is the last page's center footer." 
    pg.LeftHeader.Text = "This is the last page's header" 

    ' Note that Excel supports only distinct headers/footers 
    ' for the first page, so headers and footers on the second 
    ' and other pages are combined--the last value set overwrites 
    ' the header/footer. 

    ' See the values in the Immediate window. 
    ' Note that the code disregards errors that occur--attempting 
    ' to retrieve a header/footer setting that doesn't exist raises an error: 
    On Error Resume Next 
    Debug.Print "First page (CenterHeader) : " & pgs(1).CenterHeader.Text 
    Debug.Print "Second page (CenterHeader): " & pgs(2).CenterHeader.Text 
    Debug.Print "Second page (CenterFooter): " & pgs(2).CenterFooter.Text 
    Debug.Print "Third page (CenterFooter) : " & pgs(3).CenterFooter.Text 
    Debug.Print "Last page (LeftHeader)    : " & pgs(pgs.Count).LeftHeader.Text 
    Debug.Print "Last page (CenterFooter)  : " & pgs(pgs.Count).CenterFooter.Text 

    ' In conclusion, use the Page class to retrieve information about headers 
    ' and footers for specific pages. Use the PageSetup object to set the headers 
    ' and footers, as it's clearer to set them there. 
End Sub
```

But the values output by the `Debug.Print "Second page (CenterFooter): " & pgs(2).CenterFooter.Text` line differ from what is expected:

`Second page (CenterFooter): This is the last page's center footer`

Instead of the right: `Second page (CenterFooter): This is the second page's footer`.

I have tried different things but all the `CenterFooter` keep always the last input value. How can I change this behaviour such that each page gets the exact footer I want?

Comment: I told you: clarity is really helpful to get a prompt and accurate reply. I seriously intend to analyse each question as objectively as possible but it is not too easy if the asker shows certain attitude (if you don't care about your question, why should I?). I am sure that other people behaves like myself: the reply to a worthy question/attitude is taking it seriously and analysing the problem properly; for a careless attitude, my answer is careless (writing stuff without thinking about it and while doing other things in parallel is pretty easy). Hopefully you will learn from all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different footers/headers configurations but none of them allows to write a different value for each page. You can write a different text for the first page and for even/uneven pages; also you can add some [formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb225426%28v=office.12%29.aspx) with certain variations page to page (e.g., page number) but this is it. In Word the rules are equivalent.

Regarding the MSDN code you provided, one of its comments says:

> Note that Excel supports only distinct headers/footers for the first
>   page, so headers and footers on the second and other pages are
>   combined--the last value set overwrites the header/footer.

And thus this code is actually working as expected; although it is not too clear at first sight.

Comment: Thanks very much, varocarbas, now I need to think of a workaround!

Comment: @Joe.Net You are welcome. I have done some tests by my own and I am afraid that you don't have too many options. In Word it is easier because you can write text in any part of the document, but in Excel is a bit trickier as far as, in principle, you can just write in the "cells part". But there might be a workaround... not 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks for that, It's a bit of a pain to be honest, every page needs its own unique footer, I can't use any other part of the page, thought it was only going to take 5 minutes!

Comment: @Joe.Net In your situation, I would intend to avoid this feature (writing something on the bottom does not sound too important); or would replace it with something on which Excel does have full control (anything you can write/put in the "spreadsheet area"). But I don't think that you should waste too much time on it: the main functionalities of MS Office programs work pretty well, but the side ones, not so well... so better adapt your requirements to these main functionalities.

Comment: Thanks very much, to give a bit of context I use Excel Automation to generate what can be over 100 Excel pages. I then set the print area for each page programmatically, I cannot use a page's print area for what I want to put in the footer, so to me its a pretty significant issue. That said, using Excel has enabled me provide a solution that would be much harder to produce elsewhere.

Comment: @Joe.Net You cannot use footers/headers as you want. You might intend to "trick the system", by adding a label or something like that and move it to the position you want (but, as said, not sure about its reliability outside the "cells area"); or you might even try to perform the conversion of the Excel spreadsheet into other format (e.g., pdf) allowing you to add something on top/bottom. But the answer to your question is: you cannot use the headers/footers. If you need ideas about how to overcome this, you might post a new question explaining clearly what you want, what you tried, etc.

Comment: Sure, Thanks varocarbas and Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is resurrecting a thread from the dead, but this is actually do-able in Excel VBA. I had to figure it out as I couldn't find an acceptable solution here, so I'm leaving this for the next poor sod:

The solution is to create a subroutine to set the header and footer, and then call that routine within a loop in a different sub, calling each worksheet one at a time and managing what you want to say by variable.

So something like this:

```
Sub InsertQuoteHeaderAndFooter(ByVal shtHeader As Worksheet, strText$)

    shtHeader.PageSetup.RightFooter = "&""Calibri"" &8 &K434643" & strTxt & " | &P of &N"

End Sub
```

Then call it in a For loop, modulating shtHeader and strText as needed. Hope this helps the next archaeologist.